# Getting Twitter profile info with Firebase Auth Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, rest, twitter

I'm trying to get basic details of a user signing into my app with their Twitter account. I am able to sign them in but not too sure where to go from here.

I'm pretty sure I need to use [this](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/manage-account-settings/api-reference/get-account-verify_credentials) get request but am unsure how to structure the request. Am also a little lost which token I include.

I haven't had much experience with the REST API as you could tell. I have Postman set up so if someone could point me in the right direction about accessing the data I could take it from there.

Thanks

```
@IBAction func twitterSignupPress() {

provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in

    if error != nil {
        print("Error attempting to sign up using Twitter: \(error!)")
    } else { 

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential!) { authResult, error in
            if error != nil {
                 print("Error with Twitter signin")
            } else {
                print("Successful signin using Twitter")
                let oAuthCredential = authResult?.credential as! OAuthCredential
                print(oAuthCredential.accessToken!) // Prints token
                print(oAuthCredential.idToken) // Prints nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Was as simple as adding `authResult?.additionalUserInfo?.profile`